# Can not access to firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP in React-Native

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

After upgraded to Firebase *3.2.0* (react-native *0.30*), I'm trying to set a `TIMESTAMP` as described in the docs:

```
  import Firebase from 'firebase'
    ...
  let config = {
    apiKey:  `${ Config.firebase.apiKey }`,
    authDomain: `${ Config.firebase.authDomain }`,
    databaseURL: `${ Config.firebase.databaseURL }`,
    storageBucket: `${ Config.firebase.storageBucket }`
  }

  const firebase = Firebase.initializeApp(config)
  const created_at = firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP
```

then I get

> created_at = undefined

when debugging with Chrome' Developer Tools, `firebase.database` is a function without any `ServerValue` in it.

Any idea ?

Comment: I was calling it like this `firebase.database().ServerValue.TIMESTAMP` so anyone like me remove the parentheses

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this syntax:

```
 import Firebase from 'firebase'
```

and then:

```
 Firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP
```

Comment: import Firebase from 'firebase' will also work. The OP just needs to use Firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP instead of firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP, as the latter is not the default library import.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
import RNFirebase from "react-native-firebase"
data.timestamp = RNFirebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP;
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, even though I was using Firestore for all my data storage/retrieval using the web JS client, I had to import the Firebase Database libary at the start of my HTML like so

`<script defer src="/__/firebase/7.17.1/firebase-database.js"></script>`

Simply having `<script defer src="/__/firebase/7.17.1/firebase-firestore.js"></script>` is not enough.  After loading the `database` module, then I could access `firebase.database` stuff, like `ServerValue.TIMESTAMP`

In my case, since I am using Firestore, then I used `firebase.firestore.Timestamp.now()` instead of the `firebase.database` bits above.